# Transparent faces even with Limit Selection to Visible

Tags: edit-mode

I was wondering why the objects of this file are always displayed transparent in *Edit* mode, even with the *Limit Selection to Visible* option enabled, and no *Shading* enabled in the 3D properties panel. I think I miss something. [Here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51432) is the file.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: please don't use pasteall.org to upload files. The links expire after a few months.

Comment: ok, blend-exchange didn't want to upload but I'm trying again

Comment: it's completely stuck actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *3D View far clipping distance* is set to a very high value. The floating point representation of depth in Blenders Viewport is not layed out to handle these high values.

You can easily recreate the problem, by

1. Opening a new Blender file.
2. Selecting the cube and going into edit mode.
3. Switching to orthographic view.
4. Setting the *View > Clip > End* to `100000`.

In your file, the end clipping distance is set to `1km`. However, since your *Scene > Unit Scale* is set to 0.001, this value translates to ~1000000 BUs.